# Is there a complete source for aircraft registration information?

Tags: datasets, aircraft-registration

I am building an app that requires access to commercial aircraft registrations, in the UK to begin with and then more global as I start to expand the service.

I have found [this CAA site](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aircraft-register/G-INFO/Guidance-on-using-the-G-INFO-Database/) which works for now, but I would like to include all registered aircraft.

Comment: http://www.airframes.org/ Is a good bet. I do not know if they offer some sort of API access.

Comment: @J.Hougaard An interesting source, but not for other-than-personal use. [From the about page on airframes.org](http://www.airframes.org/about.php): *"The use of this database is free of charge for occasional (low-volume) personal lookups by private users by means of a standard web-browser. [...] It is not allowed to collect and transfer these data anywhere else. Copyright rules apply."*